# Virus detected with ClamTK (Possible infection?)

Tags: 12.04, security, antivirus, malware, clamav

I did a routine scan of my system, with ClamTK. The the anti-virus reported 3 detections.
The names of the three detections are:

1.**[PUA.Phishing.Bank]**

2.**[PUA.Phishing.Bank]**

3.**[PUA.Script.Packed-1]**

The first two are detected in the Firefox caches:

/.cache/mozilla/firefox/

The last is detected in the Chromium caches:

/.cache/chromium/Default

I know that PUA stands for potentially unwanted software. Are these false positives? Is it a Windows virus or a Linux virus? If it is a Linux virus, how will it affect my system?

Comment: antivirus on linux is known for false positives. Once you run such software, your next step is to identify the files , usually with a google search. Often only you can determine if the files are valid or not depending on your activity. FWIW worth, even the developers complain of flase positives in their FAQ - "his should put an end to the endless threads on our mailing lists." - http://www.clamav.net/doc/misc-faq.html

Answer (score 0):

The infected files are not likely to affect your Linux installation. Viruses which can affect your Linux installation are very rare!

Most likely you have navigated to a website that was compromised and a file that has some dodgy tracking code has been cached. These sorts of files are usually targeting vulnerable Windows PC's.

Try clearing your Firefox and Chrome cache and rescan, they should hopefully be gone.

If you are concerned that they might be malicious - check the quarantine area to get the virus name and then search the internet for any information on that virus.