# How to evaluate clamscan results?

Tags: clamav

I'm running

```
clamscan -r --infected --heuristic-scan-precedence=yes --detect-pua=yes --detect-structured=no
```

and am getting some results like `PUA.Html.Trojan.Agent-37075 FOUND`. Now, I don't find any instructions

- in the [PUA FAQ](https://www.clamav.net/documents/potentially-unwanted-applications-pua) nor in the [ClamAV Virus Database FAQ](https://www.clamav.net/documents/clamav-virus-database-faq)
- on the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clam_AntiVirus)

how to evaluate this result, i.e. which workflow has to be processed. Is every result to be removed immediately? Where are documentations of the results? Are there different documentations for different result types?

I'm using `clamav` 0.99+dfsg-1ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- "PUA" means "Potential Unwanted Application"
- "Html" means a webpage

And it ends there. You should have far more notices otherwise this is a [false](https://www.reddit.com/r/conspiracy/comments/4j5tdb/is_reddit_infecting_my_linuxbased_computer_with_a/) positive. [This](https://forum.ubuntu-nl.org/index.php?topic=96699.0) (dutch) shows:

```
PUA.Win.Tool.Packed-177         
PUA.Html.Trojan.Agent-37075     
PUA.Win.Trojan.Xored-1
```

... pointing to Windows. What else do you see with that line containing 37075?

Example of a clear malware problem in the browser ...

[PUA.Phishing.Bank Found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605031/pua-phishing-bank-found)

That shows a site that is considered a phishing.

Besides ClamAV/ClamTk, you can use firefox with noscript, ad aware and flashblock and scan non-confidential files downloaded with virustotal.com

Comment: Is there a way I could figure this out myself for new results I get? How do you figure this out? If there's no documentation of results I'd have to ask a question on askubuntu for every result I get. That can't be the intention of the author(s) of the software - regardless of the fact that it doesn't work well.

Comment: There should be more lines that just that 1 you used in the question. The one above it should be related (and maybe the one under it)